# Error 419 login laravel in some phone browsers

Tags: iphone, laravel, google-chrome, safari, session-cookies

I have developed an app in Laravel, and it works correctly, except when running from apple and android phones using chrome or safari. It returns error 419 and does not create the session. In the rest of browsers it works perfectly. This means that Laravel cannot be used for iphone?

I use Laravel 7.0, and the app works correctly except on apple phones with safari and android with chrome

Comment: Error 419 in laravel usually means: You did not add the CSRF token OR the token is expired. As you did not provide any code, we cannot help you find the issue. It would be nice to get the html of your login page, maybe even the controller's login function.

Comment: http://tecnolord.cat/test/login
You can try to login and register in this laravel web test with android chrome or iphne safari browser. Te sistem return 419 error. If you login or register with firefox the sistem work ok. The app test is onli the basic instalation of laravel 7.0 @RobBiermann

Comment: I tried to create an account via chrome on windows, just resets my password fields, but no error(also no account)

Comment: Only chrome Android and Safari

Comment: I try other projects in laravel and return the same isue in android chrome browser and iphone safari.
Other example with the same isue:
https://documentator.io/login

Comment: @RobBiermann if you would I get the html of my login page and the controller's login function, but it was autogenerate by laravel installation without changes.

Comment: So to confirm: You got multiple laravel projects which are all running on the same server which have the same issues with the same browsers? I would dare to state that your server is the issue. Ive also had a 419 in the past, which was caused by a misinstallation in a php-mod. Sadly, I didn't cause the issue back then, so i let the one who caused the issue fix it. So I have no further pointers in directions.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug with "same-site" option, check out here: https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/4813

Answer (score 0):

I don't know very well the cause of the problem, but I see that the session is always created well except from the mentioned browsers. In this case the session file is not generated inside storage / framework / session.
I can not understand the reason why it only happens in those browsers and in the rest it does not